# generator always returning the same glitchy thing in random sentence generator

Tags: javascript

umm its always weirdly returns a sentence that is not what i am looking for. heres the code

```
function erase(){document.open()}
alert("welcome to random sentence genereator and your sentence is on the screenand in the console below")
var b =Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
if (b="1"){var a=("i ")}
else if(b="2"){var a=("a bean ")}
else if(b="3"){var a =("a xbox ")}
else if(b="0"){var a =("sport drink ")}
else if (b="4"){var a =("some grass ")}
else if(b="5"){var a =("a rock ")}
var e=Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
if(e="0"){var p =("fell on ")}
else if(e="1"){var p =("jumped on ")}
else if(e="2"){var p =("bounced over ")}
else if(e="3"){var p =("slid on")}
else if(e="4"){var p =("slipped on")}
var n=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if(n="0"){var q=("a mountain ")}
if(n="1"){var q =("a candlestick ")}
else if(n="2"){var q =("a raw potato ")}
else if(n="3"){var q=("a book ")}
else if(n="4"){var q=("a glass bottle ")}
else if(n="5"){var q =("water ")}
else if(n="6"){var q =("fish soup ")}
var o=Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
if(o="0"){var v =("in the dark")}
if (o="1"){var v =("in the light")}
if(o="2"){var v=("in the middle of nowhere")}
if(o="3"){var v=("in a giant lemon")}
document.write(a+p+q+v)
```

why doesent it work and always weirdly return a sentence. plz awnser

Comment: Because comparison is done with `==` or `===`. Not `=`.

Comment: Aside, given that there is already an answer to your question. Here is a quick tip: Try formatting your code. You can install a tool like Prettier or do it with this tool, online: https://prettier.io/playground/

Comment: Another tip: If you initialize a variable outside your if conditional blocks you won't have to do it multiple times (i.e. `var a; if (b === 1) { a = "i " }`) and makes the intended scope of the variable a little more clear because you are trying to use it outside the blocks they are defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try following code**:

```
function erase() {
    document.open()
}
alert("welcome to random sentence genereator and your sentence is on the screen and in the console below")
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
if (b === 1) {
    var a = ("i ")
} else if (b === 2) {
    var a = ("a bean ")
} else if (b === 3) {
    var a = ("a xbox ")
} else if (b === "0") {
    var a = ("sport drink ")
} else if (b === 4) {
    var a = ("some grass ")
} else if (b === 5) {
    var a = ("a rock ")
}
var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
if (e === 0) {
    var p = ("fell on ")
} else if (e === 1) {
    var p = ("jumped on ")
} else if (e === 2) {
    var p = ("bounced over ")
} else if (e === 3) {
    var p = ("slid on ")
} else if (e === 4) {
    var p = ("slipped on ")
}
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if (n === 0) {
    var q = ("a mountain ")
}
if (n === 1) {
    var q = ("a candlestick ")
} else if (n === 2) {
    var q = ("a raw potato ")
} else if (n === 3) {
    var q = ("a book ")
} else if (n === 4) {
    var q = ("a glass bottle ")
} else if (n === 5) {
    var q = ("water ")
} else if (n === 6) {
    var q = ("fish soup ")
}
var o = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
if (o === 0) {
    var v = ("in the dark")
}
if (o === 1) {
    var v = ("in the light")
}
if (o === 2) {
    var v = ("in the middle of nowhere")
}
if (o === 3) {
    var v = ("in a giant lemon")
}
document.write(a + p + q + v)
```

Comment: Random number always generate number and not a string, you are comparing number with string which can lead you to error in future project.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a Number, so you should compare it with `b == '3'` or `b === 3`.
Beside, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)` generates a number between 0 and 4 (and never 5), so you'll never go to `b == 5` with this.

Comment: still returns the same thing

Comment: It should work if you change every `b="1"` to `b=="1"`. And same for e, n and o.

Comment: @codesforkids [Yep, it does](https://jsfiddle.net/szk3n4ax/1/).

Comment: @Ivar think using == is bad practice. Always use ===

Comment: @RahulGurujala My example is just to show that it should work. I generally agree with you that strict equality comparison is preferred.

Comment: @Ivar yes my dear programmer I got it. 